# Laravel: passing variable to Schema::create

Tags: php, laravel, controller

How can i possibly pass `$i` variable into this function?

```
$i = 0;
        foreach(request('nazwa') as $n){
            $nr = new Schemat;
            $nr->specjalizacja_id = $s->id;
            $nr->nazwa=$n;
            $nr->typ=request('typ')[$i];
        //    $nr->save();
            $i++;
        }
        $i = $i-1;

        Schema::connection('mysql')->create($s->nazwa, function($table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('pacjent_id');
            $table->integer('wizyta_id');
            for($j=$i; $j>=0; $j--){ //**Undefined variable: i ERROR**
               if(request('typ')[$j] == 0){
                  $table->integer(request('nazwa')[$j]);
               } elseif(request('typ')[$j] == 1){
                  $table->text(request('nazwa')[$j]);
               } else {
                  $table->text(request('nazwa')[$j]);
               }
            }

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use your local variable like `$i` - pass it to anonymous function using `use()`.

```
Schema::connection('mysql')
    ->create($s->nazwa, function($table) use ($i) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('pacjent_id');
        $table->integer('wizyta_id');

        for ($j = $i; $j >= 0; $j--) {
            if (request('typ')[$j] == 0) {
                $table->integer(request('nazwa')[$j]);
            } elseif (request('typ')[$j] == 1) {
                $table->text(request('nazwa')[$j]);
            } else {
                $table->text(request('nazwa')[$j]);
            }
        }

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Will accept your answer after delay

Comment: Cool. Also look at my code formatting - it's PSR2 and it's very useful. :)

Comment: Will check that out